# Do gravitational waves carry energy?

Tags: energy, gravity, gravitational-waves

We now know that gravitational waves are real. Do they carry energy? I mean thy are waves and every wave carries energy.

If they carry energy, how do they do it?

Is there any equation to describe it?

Comment: Best source i know of to understand this is Weinberg’s book, Gravitation and Cosmology, section on gravitational waves. He derives an equation for the power per unit solid angle into gravitational waves given a classical source with an energy momentum tensor.

Comment: @Wakabaloola Can you give me something from Internet?

Comment: i don’t know of any other source that is as complete and clear as Weinberg’s, might be worth googling. maybe somebody else can offer some other source material too (?)

Comment: @BenCrowell Can anyone measure this kinetic energy using equations?

Comment: @BenCrowell, the argument you quote isn't very convincing, because it only shows that energy is transferred to mechanical degrees of freedom and later to heat, but it does not show with certainty that the gravitational wave brought it. It may be that the wave just released it from the energy of field stored in the region where the masses are.

Comment: Oh, yes, those waves do carry energy! In fact, the first gravitational wave event that we actually detected radiated about three solar masses worth of energy in the form of gravitational waves (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_observation_of_gravitational_waves)...

Answer (score 1):

Yes. A gravitational wave will cause the distance between two test masses to oscillate. A local observer will detect this as an input of kinetic energy into the masses. Wald has a thorough discussion in sec. 4.4, pp. 84-86. For a freely available treatment, see Carroll, http://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/9712019 , ch. 6.

Well known examples include the loss of energy to radiation by the Hulse-Taylor system, and the spectacular amounts of energy lost in black hole mergers as detected by LIGO.

Answer (score 0):

Yes they do. They do this in the form of ripples. They distort the fabric of space time. They carry energy in the form of waves . Just like the type of distortion you can see in a `mat` when you form waves in it.
However it ( mat ) has energy and you can see it.
Same in the case of gravitational waves , they carry energy in the form of ripples , or waves .